# gcc: CLOCK_REALTIME is undeclared

Tags: c, gcc

I was trying to run the C code that I found [on this website](https://medium.com/swlh/a-performance-comparison-between-c-java-and-python-df3890545f6d)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define n 2048

double A[n][n];
double B[n][n];
double C[n][n];

int main() {

    //populate the matrices with random values between 0.0 and 1.0
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

            A[i][j] = (double) rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;
            B[i][j] = (double) rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;
            C[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    struct timespec start, end;
    double time_spent;

    //matrix multiplication
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
    time_spent = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
    printf("Elapsed time in seconds: %f \n", time_spent);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile it gcc says:

```
main.c:27:19: error: 'CLOCK_REALTIME' undeclared (first use in this function)
 clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I used *gcc-g++* from [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/) as described in [this tutorial](https://dev.to/gamegods3/how-to-install-gcc-in-windows-10-the-easier-way-422j).

I just copied the C code from the tutorial page and compiled it using

```
gcc -O3 main.c -o matrix
```

(my source file is named `main.c`).

**Possible important information: I am on Windows 10.**

**EDIT:** Compilation works just fine on Ubuntu 20.04 (as described in the article). However, can you help me get it to compile on Windows?

Comment: Maybe this will be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15746960/85696

Comment: Please add `#define _GNU_SOURCE` and `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1999309L` __on top__ of your file and try compiling then. If not, install cygwin. Install cygwin anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've got for a benchmark program I'm working on:

```c
typedef long long ticks_t;

static ticks_t ticks_per_second;

#if OS_Windows
static ticks_t get_timer_resolution()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER freq;
    if (!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq)
            || !freq.QuadPart) {
        printf("Error: cannot get Windows timer resolution.\n");
        exit(123);
    }
    return freq.QuadPart;
}

inline static ticks_t get_ticks()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER ticks;
    if (!QueryPerformanceCounter(&ticks)) {
        printf("Error: cannot get Windows timer count.\n");
        exit(123);
    }
    return ticks.QuadPart;
}
#else       // NOT WINDOWS, should be Linux / Unix
static ticks_t get_timer_resolution()
{
    return 10000000;
}

inline static ticks_t get_ticks()
{
    struct timespec t;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t);
    return (long long)t.tv_sec * 10000000 + (t.tv_nsec + 50) / 100;
}

#endif

[...]

int main() {
    [...]
    ticks_per_second = get_timer_resolution();
```

Then use `get_ticks()` just before and after what I need to time, take the difference, and scale as needed using `ticks_per_second`, e.g.

```
    nticks = nticks * 1000000 / ticks_per_second;   // convert to microsecs
```